# Java subclass constructor executes much longer

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

here is my problem:
I've got two classes, basic inheritance:

```
public class Foo1 {
    long a;
    double b;
    String c;

    Foo1(long a, double b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    Foo1(long a, double b, String c) {
         this(a, b);
         this.c = c;
    }
    ...
}

public class Foo2 extends Foo1 {
    Foo2(long a, double b) {
        super(a, b);
    }

    Foo2(long a, double b, String c) {
         super(a, b, c);
    }
    ...
}
```

And now:
- Class Foo1 creates normally from both constructors,
- Class Foo2 creates normally from 2 argument constructor, but in case of 3 argument constructor it creates noticeably longer, for example:

Creation (and other stuff going on) of 6k Foo1 and 6k Foo2, using 2 argument constructor takes 2 min, and same thing, 6k and 6k using 3 argument constractor takes like 1 hour.

I am 100% sure that this part is slowing down my program but I have absolutley no idea why... Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps because you create 6k instances of String. long and double are primitive types while String is an object

Comment: *"I am 100% sure that this part is slowing down my program"* how did you measure it?

Comment: Good to show the benchmarking code.

Comment: Creating 6k instances won't take so much, did you try to use a profiler? Indeed we;d like to see the test code and runtime settings (heap size)

Comment: @YevhenDanchenko construcor with String in superclass works fine

Comment: I just tested your code by creating 60k instances of both classes, it terminates in half a second... and I'm using an online compiler! What system are you working on?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I've measured time of each operation, I've comented this specific construcor etc

Comment: Did your code even compile? There are missing semicolon in the Foo2 definition

Comment: @Oneiros Windows 10, Java 1.8.0_131

Comment: I am 100% sure that you are wrong about this.  Please provide a MCVE or a benchmark that we can use to figure out what the real problem is.

Comment: @GabrielVince I've wrote it down here as an example, it is a part of large system which I can not share

Comment: *" I've measured time of each operation, I've comented this specific construcor etc "* then it should be easy to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from that specific part of code to post here...

Comment: perhaps check the "other stuff going on"?

Comment: Then REALLY use a profiler. At least check your memory (aren't you running at the edge of the heap?)

Comment: If you can't recreate the problem in a MCVE then the problem is not where you think it is

Comment: I bet you are calling the second constructor with new String(..). And how can you benchmark with "and other stuff going on"?

Answer (score 4):

> I am 100% sure that this part is slowing down my program

Do not optimize on a "I'm sure" basis.

Benchmark you application with a *profiler* to identify the real bottleneck.

Comment: true but I feel your post should have been a comment. You are asking the OP for more clarification by putting a profiler. Your suggestion of using a profiler to benchmark the problem areas isn't a solution to OP's question.

Comment: @RBT I don't meant it as "request for more information" (which I did in comments) but as a suggestion. Sure enough it is not the answer the OP may have expected...

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.